# Should I ask if wall was inspected for moisture?

Tags: wood, siding

My Mother lives in a community where the maintenance crew is supposed to maintain the grounds and outside of the condo buildings. I submitted a work order, because some of the wood panels on the outside of the condo were bent outward where they met with the deck. When I found out that the crew nailed the boards down, I asked via email if the wall underneath was inspected for moisture before the boards were nailed (since there were openings where the boards were warped). It has been two weeks, but I haven't received a response. Am I being too picky by asking that? It seems like any professional would have checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, checking for the cause of the problem, including moisture in the wall, seems logical. In fact, without checking it could lead to dryrot or mold.

I think I’d email them again and ask if they found dryrot or mold and let them know that if you don’t hear back this time, you’ll take it to the HOA. No response, then I’d ask the HOA.

Comment: The downside to this entire situation is that, at this point with the work order fulfilled, I wouldn't trust a thing they said after the fact anyway. "Oh sure, we checked it, and everything looked good so we re-secured it. Good to go!" ....maybe they did just that, and maybe it's true. Or maybe they didn't. If it's too late to get your own eyes on it, then I can't imagine anything they say will result in any real peace of mind. But maybe that's just me

Comment: @elrobis No, I agree, that's how they are too, despite my Mother paying $670/month in association dues.